# When I use Intrument Leak Tool,I got a NSCFString Object Leak ,But I don't know where is wrong

Tags: objective-c, core-data

```
+ (NSArray*) queryAllByEntityName:(NSString*) name AndSortColumn:(NSString*) ptyName{
//Define our entity to use
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

//Setup the Fetch Request
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];

//Define How we will sort the result
if (ptyName != nil) {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:ptyName ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptor release];
}


//Fetch the record and Handle the error
NSError *error;
NSArray *FetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[request release];
if (!FetchResults) {
    //Handle the Error
}

//Save our fetched Data to a array
return [[FetchResults copy] autorelease];}
```

I used to be a java programmer, so I am still unfamilier with memory management.
I know I have to return a autorelease object, and I did it.
Or My core-data function have problems other than NSCFString?
THx for Answer!

Comment: Is there a certain point that Leaks points to?

Comment: NSCFString leak in this code? cant find any..

Comment: I dont think this is the exact cause of your leak..But FYI you dont need to return FetchResult by copying and autoreleasing..

executeFetchRequest does return an autorelease object..you just return it.

return FetchResults;

when you receive the returned array..

NSArray *returnedArray = [[YourClassName queryAllByEntityName:...] retain];
//Now do your stuff with returnedArray...

[returnedArray release];

Comment: Also it is always good to give variable name starting with small case letters...fetchResults instead of FetchResults will be more standard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you've over retained one of the passed strings (`name` or `ptyName`) before you passed it to the method. It arrives in the local scope with to many retains and can't be disposed of when the local scope memory pool drains.

The code is otherwise technically correct but you could use a couple of improvements.

Don't use `alloc - init` when an autoreleased convenience method will do. So this:

```
if (ptyName != nil) {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:ptyName ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptor release];
}
```

... would more concisely and safely be written:

```
if (ptyName != nil) {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:ptyName ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}
```

Copying the returned array is unnecessary as is the autorelease. So this:

```
return [[FetchResults copy] autorelease];}
```

... should be like this:

```
return fetchResults;
}
```

Comment: Thx TechZen & All:
I got it, and I solve the problem. The method is what all you said.
This is my first time to post problem on stackOverFlow , and really appreciate your answer!